# Page jumps back to element scrolled into view if user scrolls immediately after

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create smooth scrolling when clicking certain anchor tags on my page. This is the on click event handler below.

```
const smoothScrollToView = (evt, id) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        const selectedNode = global.document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
        if (!selectedNode) return evt;
        selectedNode.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start',
        });
        global.window.history.pushState(null, null, `#${id}`);
    }
    return true;
};
```

It scrolls to element correctly; however, if the user should scroll immediately after the animation is done, the view jumps back to the element previously scrolled into view. If the user scrolls ~2 seconds after the animation, this behaviour does not occur. The only fix I have come across that makes it work without the jank is setting the `href` value of the `a` tag to `javascript:void(0)`, and I would very much like to avoid that. Is there something wrong with my implementation, please?

Comment: Are you sure you could not simply use the css smooth scroll property ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_scroll-behavior.asp

Comment: I did. The problem with scroll-behavior: smooth, on my project at least, is that there is a delay (~1.5 seconds) before the animation kicks off. I haven't seen any documentation on how to modify that transition's duration, so I had to forego that choice.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://github.com/zengabor/zenscroll to implement the smooth scroll.